# How to add getFollowers functionality with ES6 Classes?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning more about JavaScript and I want to build a follow/following functionality with ES6 Classes. I've made some good progress but I'm stuck on how to add the method to get followers. Can you give me some help?

Code so far:

```
class User {
    id = undefined
    username = undefined
    following = []
    
    constructor({ id, username }) {
        this.id = id
        this.username = username        
    }

    follow(user) {
    if (this === user) throw Error("Cannot follow yourself")
        this.following.push(user)
    }

    get followers() {
        return "???"
    }
}

const user1 = new User({ id: 1, username: 'foo' })
const user2 = new User({ id: 2, username: 'bar' })

user1.follow(user2)
user2.follow(user1)

console.log(user1.following) // people that user1 follows
console.log(user1.followers) // people that follows user1
```

Comment: `return this.following`??????

Comment: Since the followers aren't linked in a given user, getting followers is a process of iterating over all users, checking to see if their `following` array contains the user of interest.

Comment: @epascarello read the question again. I want to get the followers not the following ones.

Comment: @Ouroborus the problem is that I don't have access to all User instances in that method and this approach is also very expensive.  Going through every user instance and perform this operation is time complexity of O(n2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this code:

```js
class User {
  id = undefined
  username = undefined
  following = []
  follower = []
  constructor({ id, username }) {
      this.id = id
      this.username = username     
  }

  follow(user) {
  if (this === user) throw Error("Cannot follow yourself")
      this.following.push(user.username)
      user.follower.push(this.username)
  }

  get followings() {
      return this.following
  }
  get followers(){
     return this.follower
  }
}

const user1 = new User({ id: 1, username: 'foo' })
const user2 = new User({ id: 2, username: 'bar' })
const user3 = new User({ id: 3, username: 'john doe' })
user1.follow(user2)
user2.follow(user1)
user1.follow(user3)

console.log(`followings: ${user1.following}`) // people that user1 follows
console.log(`followers: ${user1.followers}`); // people that follows user1
```

Comment: This is wrong because you're assuming the user I'll follow will also follow me back but this is not true in all cases.

Comment: wow great ...   I am doing too much complex.  ...thanks

Comment: @GabrielLinassi no sir, please check the code again. lol

Comment: @GabrielLinassi Yeah, this looks correct to me. It could do with an explanation: They've added a `follower` field. They update both `this.following` and `user.follower` in the `follow()` function. This tracks the the directional follow on both ends which allows you to easily get the follower list without having to search the other users.

Comment: @RezaZand You're right. My bad.

Comment: @RezaZand I liked its simplicity, I'll perform some edge case tests

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.map() to find followers name:

```
class User {
    id = undefined
    username = undefined
    following = []
    
    constructor({ id, username }) {
        this.id = id
        this.username = username        
    }

    follow(user) {
    if (this === user) throw Error("Cannot follow yourself")
        this.following.push(user)
    }

    get followings() {
        return this.following.length ? this.following.map(ele => ele.username) : '';
    }
}

const user1 = new User({ id: 1, username: 'foo' })
const user2 = new User({ id: 2, username: 'bar' })
const user3 = new User({ id: 3, username: 'user3' })
const user4 = new User({ id: 4, username: 'user4' })

user1.follow(user2);
user2.follow(user1);
user1.follow(user3);
user1.follow(user4);

console.log(user1.followings);
console.log(user2.followings);
```

output:

```
[ 'bar', 'user3', 'user4' ]
[ 'foo' ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I guess you didn't understand it. I need to get the information of `who is following` that user. If I want to get who that user is following, `user.following` does the job.